# How can I update and delete record in mongo using pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, python-2.7, pymongo

I am trying to do insert/update/delete using pymongo. my insert works, but update and delete does not success

```
def update(self,test1):
print "hi"
    client=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
    db=client.test  
    collection=db.test1
    # result = collection.test1.update_one({'col1': 1}, {'$set': {'col2': 'name'}})
    result = collection.test1.update_one(
        {"col4": 'fddf'},
        {
            "$set":
            {
                "col1":'12.0'                    
            }
        }, upsert=False
        )
```

Delete

```
def Delete(self,test1):

    client=MongoClient('localhost',27017)
    db=client.test  
    collection=db.test1
    db.test1.remove({"_id": ObjectId("5a880803afe40825990e7255")})
```

Also it does not give any error. But when I check mongo table, it does not change.

Any update much appricated.

Comment: try db.test1.update_one()

Comment: What document are you trying to update? _Nitpick:_ I'm not sure there is any benefit of encapsulating database connection in each function.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule: `{"col4": 'fddf'},
        {
            "$set":
            {
                "col1":'12.0'                    
            }
        }, upsert=False
        )`

Comment: When you set `col1` to `12.0` in the document `{col4: 'fddf'}`, you delete a different document where `col1` is `1.0`

Comment: @OluwafemiSule i also trying without delete function but same issue

Comment: @Astro update working fine but when i try to delete record using `id` it's gives error `global name 'ObjectId' is not defined`

Comment: @Aasif for the `ObjectId` error try to add this at top of your code: `from bson.objectid import ObjectId`

Comment: @Arount thanks  it's work